# What does : ca. 1828 mean? ca. before a date?

Tags: abbreviations

Could you tell me what "ca. 1828" means? i.e. "ca." before a date?
What if it says "First half of 12th century (c.a. 1175)?". That seems to contradict itself...

Answer (score 11):

It means *circa*, which means *around* in the sense of *more or less* or *approximately*.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circa

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/circa

Answer (score 1):

ca. is an abbreviation from circa meaning around. So ca. 1828 means around 1828.